# Каскадное удаление данных из той же таблицы EF (Code first)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Есть таблица

```
public class Category : BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Category> Children { get; set; }      
}
```

Необходимо что бы при удалении 1 Category так же удалились все Children именно в БД. Реализую через каскадное удаление

```
builder.Entity<Category>()
       .HasMany(c => c.Children)
       .WithOne(p => p.Parent)
       .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Но при выполнении миграции выпадает ошибка:

`Введение ограничения внешнего ключа (FOREIGN KEY) "FK_Categories_Categories_ParentId" для таблицы "Categories" может привести к появлению циклов или множественных каскадных путей. Укажите ON DELETE NO ACTION или ON UPDATE NO ACTION либо измените другие ограничения внешнего ключа (FOREIGN KEY). Не удалось создать ограничение или индекс. См. описание предыдущих ошибок.`

Что нужно исправить?

Comment: А что там в предыдущих ошибках?

Comment: Какая СУБД используется? Sql Server?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov MsSQL, Пред ошибки Failed executing DbCommand (81ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
ALTER TABLE [Categories] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Categories_Categories_ParentId] FOREIGN KEY ([ParentId]) REFERENCES [Categories] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE;

Comment: Не пишите в комментариях. Отредактируйте вопрос.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да какая разница, как это сделать меня интересует?

Comment: Проблема решена? Если да, опубликуйте ответ. Если нет, **ОТРЕДАКТИРУЙТЕ** вопрос!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov зачем мне публиковать ответ когда никто не может даже подсказать. В вопросе все подробно изложено

Comment: Невозможно подсказать, когда в вопросе не хватает всей необходимой информации. Которую вы зачем-то засунули в комментарий. / Когда вы опубликовали вопрос, он появился на главной странице сайта, его посмотрели - информации не хватает - ответить не смогли. Вы, вместо того, чтобы предоставить эту информацию, скрываете её (о появлении новых комментариев никто не знает, уясните это). А если бы _отредактировали_ вопрос, он снова появился бы на главной - и тогда ответ мог бы появиться.

Comment: _зачем мне публиковать ответ_ - ага, принято.